# Audio Stream error in java while trying to play a .wav file

Tags: java, audio, wav

When i try to play a sound in java, the compiler throws an error saying that "java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream"

I tried testing it with many different types of wav, but still seems like doesn't want to work.

```
package music;

import sun.audio.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class music {
static AudioPlayer amp = AudioPlayer.player;
static AudioStream strm;
static AudioData adata;
static ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    frame.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new AL());
    frame.show(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public static class AL implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        playmusic();
    }}


public static void playmusic()
{

    try {
        strm = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\smashed\\Desktop\\GameaudioTest\\omnidirectionalgunsound.wav"));
        adata = strm.getData();
        loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(adata);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    amp.start(loop);


}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any playback device installed?

Comment: I guess? but shouldn't java be the playback device.

Comment: I imagine that you need to have at least one sound device installed, otherwise operating system won't let you play sound. Can you play those wavs in any media player in the computer?

Comment: Yeah,  I have a laptop.

Comment: sun.audio is restricted API. Why are you not using javax.sound?

Comment: I can't because it's not a part of the Javax class. I tried it as many other sources said to use that but I cannot import it brotha

Comment: What version of java do you have? Javax.sound should be part of Java since 1.3

Comment: I have 1.7 I have Javax but sound is not a part of the class

Comment: So example project like this one: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html doesn't work? Note it is not just javax.sound, but rather javax.sound.sampled.*